# Conditional expressions look always false

Tags: conditionals, syntax

Experimenting with conditional expressions, namely with this trivial if...

```
\def\testvar{testvalue}
\if\testvar{testvalue}{istrue}\else{isfalse}\fi
```

I get always `isfalse`. I think I did everything as I should have done, yet I simply can not make it true.

What do I mislook?

Comment: You're comparing `t` with `e` and of course this returns false. Please, check how `\if` works in TeX by Topic.

Comment: @egreg I tried to understand your comment, then I tried `\if{\testvar}{testvalue}`, result is again false.

Comment: @egreg I check how if works.

Comment: @egreg To check it fairly, I find the problem that there is unthinkably amount of text about various \ifx, \newif \if... but nothing about \if at all. I see examples. Based on these examples, I have my try. And it does not want to work.

Comment: You want to use `\ifx`, not `\if`.

Comment: the test in your comment is comparing `{` with `t` which is false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but you got the syntax and working of `\if` completely wrong.

When TeX finds `\if` it starts expanding the following tokens until finding two unexpandable tokens. It then compares these two according to their character code (control sequences are considered to have their own character code).

Thus your `\if\testvar` immediately becomes `\if testvar` and TeX compares `t` with `e`, which have different character codes.

With legacy TeX programming, you can compare *meanings* with `\ifx`:

```
\def\fixedvalue{testvalue}% for following comparisons

\def\testvar{testvalue}

% this will return true
\ifx\testvar\fixedvalue
  something (not in braces)%
\else
  something else (not in braces)%
\fi

\def\testvar{whatever}

% this will return false
\ifx\testvar\fixedvalue
  something (not in braces)%
\else
  something else (not in braces)%
\fi
```

Comment: Tyvm!!! So if I understand, `\ifx` it can only compare macro results and no hardcoded texts?

Comment: @peterh it compares two tokens, they do not have to be macros.  `\ifx t#1` will be true if the first argument starts with `t` for example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So, comparing "t" to "tttt" will result a true? What type of comparison is it, prefix check?

Comment: `ttt` is not a token, so it would compare `t` and `t` the following two `tt` would still be in the input stream until after the comparison

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay, then what is a token in Tex? Any character and `\`-word?

Comment: @peterh `word` is 4 tokens. a token is a character or a control sequence such as `\foo`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay. And a braced expression (`{thing}`)?

Comment: @peterh That's seven tokens.

Comment: @egreg Isn't there any trick to have a `if (a==b) { ... }` control without defining both "a" and "b" as `\\`-variables?

Comment: @peterh This much depends on what you want to do. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @egreg I actually solved the problem, instead `\ifx\testvar{testvalue}\fi` I used `\def\testvalue{testvalue}\ifx\testvar\testvalue`. So it works, but it is ugly. I believe, there should be some way to compare a string to a variable. Does a better solution exist for that?